# Using --array and --nodelist in sbatch

Tags: matlab, slurm

Because of the limitations in how Matlab will utilize resources on a computing cluster, I want to create several jobs, each of which uses all of the cores on a given node. I can use the --array option in conjunction with other parameters to make sure that I get each job on a separate node. However, for some reason the slurm schedule on our cluster is putting my jobs on nodes which are already in use, even though I'm trying to max out the cores on a given node using the -c option:

```
#SBATCH --array=1-2
#SBATCH -t 24:00:00
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -c 20
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu 4000

module add ~/matlab/2014a

srun matlab -nodisplay -r "myfun($SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID);quit"
```

Using the --exclusive option doesn't seem to change anything. I've been having the same problem with single tasks as well, and my workaround has been to check which nodes aren't in use and request those specifically with the --nodelist option. Is there a way to use --array in conjunction with --nodelist so that each job and node in the list are matched in one-to-one correspondence? Right now SLURM is trying to use all the nodes for each job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possibilities:

1. Either the nodes have ghost jobs running outside of Slurm's control either because of ill-terminated previous jobs, or because of unfair cluster usage by other users. As Slurm does not check the load of nodes before allocating them, you can face the situation you are describing.
2. Or, the `Shared` parameter of `slurm.conf` could be set to `Force'  to deny you the use of`--exclusive` and hyperthreading could be enabled, leading Slurm to consider it has 40 cpus per node
3. Or the `Shared` parameter of `slurm.conf` could be set to something else than `Exclusive` while the nodes are in two distinct partitions, a configuration that leads to node over-subscription.

Use the `scontrol show config` command to get more information about the configuration.

Comment: `scontrol show config` did not list a parameter called "Shared," but `sinfo -l` did show that "Share" is listed as "Force" for all the partitions. I'm curious about your comment about hyperthreading. Our cluster is set to `SelectType = select/cons_res; SelectTypeParameters = CR_CORE_MEMORY`. This means that I don't have to ask for individual threads, correct? Our nodes have 20 cores, each with 2 threads. So the correct resource request would be `-N 1; -c 20`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes, but make sure the output of `sinfo -Nl` in column CPUS is indeed 20. (Slurm can be configured to handle hardware threads as if they were actual cores.)

Comment: Ahh, so I checked the info for `SelectTypeParameters = CR_CORE_MEMORY`, and it turns out that in this case _On nodes with hyper-threads, each thread is counted as a CPU to satisfy a job's resource requirement_. `sinfo -l -N` confirms that each node indeed has 40 cpus. Setting `-c 40` seems to have fixed my problem; I now appear to be getting nodes to myself like I would expect. Thanks - In your answer, do you mind changing "...Slurm to consider it has 20 cpus per node" to 40? I think that's what you meant.

Comment: Absolutely. It turned out to be a combination of 2 & 3, so you covered all the bases!